# Is it acceptable to have three call-to-action buttons?

Tags: user-behavior, buttons, user-expectation, modal-windows, call-to-action

I'm working on an application that displays a dialog box. This dialog box prompts users to switch to a new editor. That will be the main call-to-action (CTA).

The 2nd CTA will be to retain their current editor, as an option if the user is not ready to make the switch yet.

The 3rd CTA allows them to view their changes, which is a somewhat important option, since this dialog box shows up after they've made edits to their template, and our users typically want to view changes they've made immediately after.

I don't think it's common to display 3 CTAs. The 3rd CTA from the right could probably be less prominent - maybe just a simple link instead of a button, but even then, I don't think I remember seeing a pattern like this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's a similar situation at the Github Issues report, where there's a `SUBMIT` button and a field to write the issue, but instead of having the `PREVIEW` as a button, it's a **tab**:

[image: Github Issue]

With this the CTA buttons will be just `SUBMIT` and `CANCEL`.

---

If this is a *Modal* or a *Pop up window*, the `CANCEL` button is unnecessary as such, the `X` in the upper right corner is sufficient. The three original CTA buttons are reduced to just one, the most relevant.

---

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anything like this in common use either.  I often ask myself if an element (especially a button) is relevant to the content around it before making that decision.  From what you have described, the 3rd button does not have relevancy to the block.  If the dialog that pops up has content that describes switching to the new editor or sticking with legacy, then provides two buttons to do those two tasks, that 3rd button feels out of place.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not a good idea to have more than one 'primary action' for a given task/transaction per page, but it is not uncommon to have one or more 'secondary action' since not all tasks or transactions are designed (or user friendly) to have only two choices (when one of them is likely to be cancel or to go back). Examples of multiple buttons for a task can be seen in tables that have functions to interact with individual cells, or on card elements that have richer contents, but examples of multiple call to action buttons on a page is less common (especially when you already have many buttons on the page).

Keeping one primary action and probably no more than two secondary actions allows you to apply a consistent look and feel to the application and generally doesn't break too many usability rules. Often one or more of the secondary actions is 'disguised' as a link instead of a button to help remove some of the visual confusion (when it makes sense to do so).